# Querying a custom post type, but not show duplicates

Tags: custom-post-types, php, query

I have a custom post type created called 'classes'. Within there i have a taxonomy set up as a category, so because of this there can be multiple occurrences of classes. 
Example:

**Cat 1:**
Class 1
Class 2

**Cat 2:**
Class 1
Class 3

**Cat 3:** 
Class 3
Class 4

Where there is the 2 occurrences of 'Class 1' for example, they are 2 separate posts, just with the same post name.

I then want to output the classes on their page, but not show duplicates of the post name. 

The duplicate posts obviously have different slugs (for example: myurl.com/class-1 and then myurl.com/class-1-1), but i want to be able to only show one occurences of a post if the post name is the same.

Below is the simple query i have so far, but not sure how to not show duplicates.

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query("post_type=classes".'&paged='.$paged);
?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh iv figured out a way to do this:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
      'post_type'     => 'classes',
      'orderby'       => 'title',
      'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $unique_titles = array();
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $title = get_the_title();
        if( ! in_array( $title, $unique_cities ) ) :
            $unique_titles[] = $title;
    ?>
```